# number of comparisons of binary search

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

What is the total number of comparisons necessary to locate all the n sorted distinct integers in an array using binary search?  I think the number is *n log<sub>2</sub> n* (2 is the base), but I am not sure. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an exact answer, then it is clearly **not** N log(N) or N log<sub>2</sub>(N).  For most integers N, logN and log<sub>2</sub> are not rational, but the number of comparisons must be an integer value.

Also, the exact answer will depend on implementation details of the binary search algorithm. For example, if a "comparison" is a simple relation that returns true and false, more comparisons are required than when a "comparison" returns negative, zero or positive.  (In the latter case, you can short circuit when the algorithm hits the key early.)

Answer (score 1):

It takes `log2 n` to find each one, and it needs to be done `n` times, so `n log n` it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it takes `n log m`

Where m is the size of the array, so `log m` to find a value.
And then you do this `n` times for the `n` distinct integers.

So `n log m` in total.

Comment: more detail about my question:the search algorith is:
int left = 0,right = array.length()-1;
while(left<=right){
  int middle = (left+right)/2;
if(array[middle]==key){
return true;
}else if(array[middle]<key){
left=middle+1;
}else{
right = middle-1;
}
}
return false;

another assumption: we are not allowed to reuse the result from ohter searches; we can only perform each search separately.
my answer should be ceiling(nlong2n) (2 is the base).

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought it was known in advance how many distinct integers to find (= n) in a sorted array of arbitrary length (= m). My bad.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, now I am clear. I think what Stephen C said is true. I think we cannot actually work out a formula for this question unless we have a exact value. However, if the n=2^n -1,like 511(2^9 -1), it is easy to compute. For 511, total number of comparisons = 1x1 + 2X2 + 3X4 + 4X8 + 5X16 + 6X32 + 7X64 + 8X128 + 9X256 = 4097.

Answer (score 0):

There will be at most (2 * log<sub>2</sub>n + 1) rounded down(so 7.6 => 7) comparisons for 1 number.

When we land on some number in array, first we check if it is the one we are looking for.
(== first comparison).
After that we check if it smaller (or greater) (second comparison).

To find the number, we must process at most log<sub>2</sub>n numbers.

And we must make the last comparison on the last number, to check that this is the one.

So looking for 16 in [1..16] will take 2*log<sub>2</sub>16 + 1 = 9 comparisons (assuming we land on these numbers: 8, 12, 14, 15, 16). And looking for 10 in [1..10] will take 2*log<sub>2</sub>10 + 1 = 7.6 => 7 (Assuming we land on these numbers: 5, 8, 9, 10).

So for n numbers there will be at most n times more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, now I am clear. I think what Stephen C said is true. I think we cannot actually work out a formula for this question unless we have a exact value. However, if the n=2^n -1,like 511(2^9 -1), it is easy to compute. For 511, total number of comparisons = 1x1 + 2X2 + 3X4 + 4X8 + 5X16 + 6X32 + 7X64 + 8X128 + 9X256 = 4097.